# Register multiple Serilog Loggers for ILogger<T> with Autofac

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac, serilog

I have a **.NET5 WorkerService** project that contains many `BackgroundService` classes and they all have their own `ILogger<T>` construction parameters. I want to use **Autofac** to register a different `SerilogProvider` for each `ILogger<T>`, and automatically configure the File sink related to the `BackgroundService` class name for it.

For example:

This is a `BackgroundService`.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

I hope to automatically complete the work equivalent to the following code:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
    {
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File(nameof(Worker)).CreateLogger();
        builder.Register((c, p) =>
            new LoggerFactory(new ILoggerProvider[] 
            {
                new SerilogLoggerProvider(logger)
            })).As<ILoggerFactory>();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>))
                .As(typeof(ILogger<>)).SingleInstance();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    });
```

Of course, there is more than one `BackgroundService`. So is there a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

**The first thing you could do is [use scoped services like it shows in the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)** You can register things in a child lifetime scope that only apply to that scope.

> Minor disclaimer - I'm not running all this through a compiler and testing it out first. I may have some typos or something you'll have to tweak.

In the docs they split the "thing that does work" and the `BackgroundService` apart. You'd have to do the same. In the docs, the "thing that does work" (where you'd have your separate logger) is the `ScopedProcessingService`.

```cs
internal interface IScopedProcessingService
{
    Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
}

internal class ScopedProcessingService : IScopedProcessingService
{
    private int executionCount = 0;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
    // This will be the special per-service logger you want.
    public ScopedProcessingService(ILogger<ScopedProcessingService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            executionCount++;

            _logger.LogInformation(
                "Scoped Processing Service is working. Count: {Count}", executionCount);

            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}

// This is the background service itself - you won't do the work
// in here because you want the logging to come out of your special
// logger.
public class ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> _logger;

    // This is not going to get the special logger.
    public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services, 
        ILogger<ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service running.");

        await DoWork(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is working.");

        // Here's the good bit - you need to register your special
        // logger just for this lifetime scope.
        //
        // First, get the lifetime scope that resolved this BackgroundService.
        var parent = Services.GetRequiredService<ILifetimeScope>();

        // Now create a child scope and register your special logger.
        // All the other stuff - registering the generic types and
        // things that are NOT specific to this special logger factory -
        // can go in the main container that you configure during
        // HostBuilder.ConfigureContainer like you already have.
        using (var scope = parent.BeginLifetimeScope(b =>
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo
                .File(nameof(ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService))
                .CreateLogger();
            b.Register((c, p) =>
                new LoggerFactory(new ILoggerProvider[] 
                {
                    new SerilogLoggerProvider(logger)
                })).As<ILoggerFactory>();
        ))
        {
            // This is how the scoped service will get the
            // special logger - resolve from the scope.
            var scopedProcessingService = 
                scope.Resolve<IScopedProcessingService>();
            await scopedProcessingService.DoWork(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Consume Scoped Service Hosted Service is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

You could make that whole `BeginLifetimeScope` call into an extension method so basically it could all happen at once and your code would be nice and clean.

**The second thing you could do is use keyed services.** A [keyed service](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) helps you identify a specific service registration with a key. You could combine that with [attribute filters](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#keyfilterattribute) to inject a specific `ILoggerFactory` (not the actual generic `ILogger<T>` but the factory that can create it).

First, you'd probably want to make a method for the registrations.

```cs
public static void RegisterLoggerFactory(
  this ContainerBuilder builder,
  string name)
{
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .WriteTo
          .File(name)
          .CreateLogger();
    // The factory can be a single, named instance -
    // the logger instances are the transient things.
    builder.Register((c, p) =>
        new LoggerFactory(new ILoggerProvider[] 
        {
            new SerilogLoggerProvider(logger)
        }))
        .Keyed<ILoggerFactory>(name)
        .SingleInstance();
}
```

Now when you set up your container, you'll have to do that for all the background services.

You also need to register the service using Autofac, not using the `AddHostedService` extension. [From the code for `AddHostedService`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/bdc3beedabad610723b62f484f0ff7be6c97d87e/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs#L21) all it's doing is registering it as a singleton `IHostedService`. We need to use Autofac so we can tell it to use the keyed attribute.

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
    {
        // We're not doing anything with ILogger<T> because
        // we'll get that from the factory.
        builder.RegisterLoggerFactory(nameof(Worker));

        // Register the service using Autofac. Make sure
        // to enable attribute filtering. You might even be
        // able to make another extension method to make this
        // cleaner or less repetitious.
        builder.RegisterType<Worker>()
          .As<IHostedService>()
          .SingleInstance()
          .WithAttributeFiltering();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        // Not doing this anymore!
        // services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    });
```

In each service, you need to add an attribute to the constructor so it knows which logger factory to use. For your `ILogger<T>` you'll get that from the factory.

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    // It'll be a non-generic logger but that's OK, it'll be right.
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Worker([KeyFilter(nameof(Worker))] ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // loggerFactory is the keyed one that was registered
        // special for this service.
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(Worker))
    }
}
```

Again, you could refactor some of that, like you could move the `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger` into the Autofac registration and have a keyed `ILogger` instead of a keyed `ILoggerFactory` if you wanted. You could do all sorts of stuff to refactor and remove the duplicate code. But this is the gist - using keyed services with the filter attribute.

---

Either way here would work. **If it was me, I feel like the keyed service way of things is probably the easiest and doesn't require so much change of the original code.**

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I also tried to use ```builder.RegisterType(typeof(Logger<>).MakeGenericType(..)).As(typeof(ILogger<>).MakeGenericType(..)).WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(ILoggerFactory), loggerFactory));``` (```loggerFactory``` is constructed manually) to register, the effect is acceptable. But no matter which way, I still need to use ```builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>)).SingleInstance()```
to register the ```ILogger``` that is not in the ```BackgroundService``` to capture system logs. Is there any other better way to implement it?

Comment: Register non-service-specific things like you are now in the startup. The things in the child scopes are overrides.